# Choices with labels in Manipulate: is this a bug?

Tags: bugs, manipulate

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

---

The following control form is documented for `Manipulate`:

[image]

If I evaluate

```
Manipulate[x, {x, {1 -> 4, 2 -> 5}}]
```

then I see

[image]

The initial value of `x` is not `1` but `1 -> 4`.  Shouldn't it be `1` instead? Is this a bug?  If I click the button with the label "4" then `x` does get set to `1`, but not before that.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. You can workaround it by giving `x` an initial value, e.g., `{{x, 1}, {1->4, 2->5}}`